# Enabling gzip compression in apache2 web server

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, gzip

I am trying to enable the zgip compression in apache2 web server, a quick googling helped me to fetch some instructions and I got to know that I need to edit httpd.conf which is inside /etc/apache2/ but my ubuntu 10.04 server doesnt have any content inside httpd.conf file and I also had a look into apache.conf file but could not find "LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so"

So where can I find this lines so that I can edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Debian based distros, you can enable it by executing:

```
$ sudo a2enmod deflate
```

The configuration is located at `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf`.